# Help with XmlDataSource.XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have this simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Schedule>
    <CATEGORY>FAMILY</CATEGORY>
    <LOCATIONS>119</LOCATIONS>
  </Schedule>
  <Schedule>
    <CATEGORY>ADULTS</CATEGORY>
    <LOCATIONS>314</LOCATIONS>
  </Schedule>
</DocumentElement>
</xml>
```

I am binding it to a GridView through a XmlDataSource. I need to select elements having Category=Family. I set XmlDataSource.XPath to these expressions but they return no results:

```
/DocumentElement/Schedule[CATEGORY = 'FAMILY']
/DocumentElement/Schedule/CATEGORY[. = 'FAMILY']
```

What am I doing wrong? Do you know of useful documentation with examples? I really tried to find one but could not. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml should not be enclosed in an xml element.  Remove the `</xml>` from the end.

With that you should have valid xml and this should select the Schedule element with a category element whose value = Family:

```
/DocumentElement/Schedule[CATEGORY = "FAMILY"]
```

A good source of examples can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx